# Inverse triangle equality

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why exactly can you take the absolute value of one side of this inequality and assume it is still true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66621/why-exactly-can-you-take-the-absolute-value-of-one-side-of-this-inequality-and-as)

Why is $||a|-|b|| \ge |a|-|b|$, tried a lot (like comparing to quadratics), but couldn't find the answer. Can anyone help me in the right direction?

Regards,
Kevin

Comment: I think you want $||a|-|b||\leq|a-b|$.

Comment: Thijs, Yes, you are correct. This question is not about reverse triangle inequality. I misread.

Comment: @Sri: The title is misleading, so I don't blame you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the common triangle inequality
$$
\|x\| + \|y\| \geq \|x+y\|
$$
to the variables $x=(|a|-|b|)$ and $y=|b|$

Comment: no triangle inequality needed, its much simpler, much more basic!

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**: Writing $x = |a| - |b|$, the expression reduces to $|x| \geq x$...

Comment: yes, this is much more elegant way of what [I tried to say](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66692/inverse-triangle-equality/66700#66700)! +1!

Answer (score 0):

You want to prove $|a| - |b| \le ||a| - |b||$.

**It is very simple! No triangle equality complications!** Just simply split it into two cases:

1. $|a| - |b| \le 0$, then the theorem is  obvious because clearly $0 \le ||a| - |b||$.
2. $|a| - |b| > 0$, then $||a| - |b|| = |a| - |b|$.

QED.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Stupid me! It was indeed $||a|-|b||\le|a-b|$

I did it this way, is it OK?

$||a|-|b||^2=(|a|-|b|)^2=|a|^2+|b|^2-2|a||b|$

$=a^2+b^2-2|ab|$

$\le a^2+b^2-2ab$

$=(a-b)^2=|a-b|^2$

So:

$||a|-|b||^2 \le |a-b|^2$

And therefor:

$||a|-|b|| \le |a-b|$

Comment: Yes, that works.